# My app icon animation on Home screen

Tags: ios, ios7

I tried to have a gif file as my app Icon. it did not work.

How to have my app icon animated on homescreen just like how Clock App icon?
Is there any API or anything?

Comment: No official API for this...

Comment: You cannot. The clock app is Apple's so they can do it.

Comment: Your icon must be a plain old PNG.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the iOS SDK does not allow you to change or animate your apps icon. Apple's owned apps are an exception.